Importar valores de cotizaciones del mercado argentino a Google Sheet
¡Hola!
Estoy intentando importar los Tickers de los Cedears y sus respectivos últimos precios. Estoy intentando con la siguiente función:
=IMPORTHTML("https://portfoliopersonal.com/Cotizaciones/Cedears"; "table"; 1)

El problema es que solo me devuelve la "primer página", no todos los activos. Es decir, los primeros 50 valores de los 311.
Estoy intentando importar estos datos para armar mi propia cartera. Las funciones con GOOGLEFINANCE, del BCBA, suelen traer errores o directamente #NA.
Cualquier guía es bienvenida.
Muchas gracias

¿La página portfoliopersonal.com es tuya? Este tipo de cosas suelen hacerse consultando a una API que expone los datos para ser consumidos. En la petición a la API puedes indicar límites tales como los primeros N registros donde N es la cantidad, los registros que empiezan por la letra C, donde C es el carácter de la letra requerida, etc. Hay APIs gratuitas, de pago, o puedes programar la tuya propia.

Gracias por la guía!
No es mi página, consultando me dijeron que debo pedir autorización para poder conectarme a su API. Así que ahora estoy esperando eso.
Muchas gracias!
